# how to write a fieldValue.contains("someString") query in MongoDB that works for find and aggregation functions

Tags: mongodb

I need to implement fieldValue.contains("someString") search in MongoDB query?

the solution that I found is

```
db.main.find(  { $where: "this.content.indexOf('someString') != -1" } );
```

and it works fine for a find function.

but when I do the same in Aggregation function

```
db.foo.aggregate(
    {
        $match: 
                { $where: "this.content.indexOf('someString') != -1" }
    },
    {
        $project :
                {
                    _id : 1,
                    words : 1
                }
    },
    {
        $unwind : "$words"
    },
    {
        $group : {
                    _id : { tags : "$words" },
                    count : { $sum : 1 }
                }
    },
    {
        $sort: {count:-1}
    },
    {
        $limit : 5
    }
);
```

I've got this result:

```
{
        "errmsg" : "exception: $where is not allowed inside of a $match aggregation expression",
        "code" : 16395,
        "ok" : 0
}
```

The question: how to write a fieldValue.contains("someString") query in MongoDB that works for find and aggregation functions.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a [regular expression](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions) for that:

```
$match: { content: /someString/ }
```

You should use a regular expression instead of a `$where` for the `find` case, too, as it's more efficient.

```
db.main.find( { content: /someString/ } );
```

Comment: Thank you Johny, I thought where is more efficient.  Is there something more efficient than regular expression?

Comment: @Cherven `$where` is definitely less efficient; see the [big warning in the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_where).  A regular express is the most efficient solution for this use case.

Comment: Update 2016: You should now create a text index, and use `$text` to search. See [text search in the aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/).

Comment: @BenedictLewis A text index is often a better option now, but it doesn't provide partial string matching like a regex, so it depends.